# Array items length is not working inside the function

Tags: javascript, list, function, reduce

I want to filter an item and return only the longest word with out special characters (#$%^&*)  but the length inside reduce function doesn't work.

```js
//that what I tried
function LongestWord(sen) {
    let myarr = sen.match(/\w+/gi);
    myarr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
        return acc.length > curr.length;
    });
    return result;
}
LongestWord("i cant solve th%^*is");
```

Comment: Your code is producing an error.  Always check the browser's development console for errors.

Comment: The `reduce` callback is supposed to return *a string* (in your case); you're just returning a boolean. You're also not doing anything with the eventual result of the `reduce` call.

Comment: @David While OP didn't copy the literal error message, they clearly indicated that this is the case, didn't they?!

Comment: `reduce` is probably the wrong solution for this task.

Comment: @Andy It's a perfectly fine tool for this task.

Comment: OK, let me rephrase:  there are probably better ways to solve this than using `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the word instead of a boolean value inside of `reduce`, beside the missing assignment or return of the result of reducing.

```js
function longestWord(sen) {
    let myarr = sen.match(/\w+/gi);
    return myarr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
        return acc.length > curr.length ? acc : curr;
    });
}
console.log(longestWord("i cant solve th%^*is"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reducing function should accumulate either the longest word, or just its length, in your case it accumulates a boolean (and tries to compare its `length` property, which for a boolean is simply undefined). That would be one way to do it:

```
function LongestWord2(sen) {
  const myarr = sen.match(/\w+/gi);

  return myarr.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    return Math.max(acc, curr.length)
  }, 0);
}
```

Or, without `reduce`, but `map` and `Math.max` instead:

```
function LongestWord3(sen) {
  const myarr = sen.match(/\w+/gi);
  const lengths = myarr.map(word => word.length);
  return Math.max(...lengths);
}
```